# FTX US API returns 'Not logged in: Invalid signature' error

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to create a new subaccount with FTX US API
When I'm sending the request it returns

```
{'success': False, 'error': 'Not logged in: Invalid signature', 'errorCode': 'not_logged_in'}
```

Here's what's going on in my code

reqs.py:

```
REQUEST_TYPES = {'all': '/wallet/all_balances', 'sub': '/subaccounts'}

async def post(end, payload):
  ts = int(time.time() * 1000)
  request = Request('POST', f'{ENDPOINT}{REQUEST_TYPES[end]}', data=payload)
  prepared = request.prepare()
  session = Session()
  signature_payload = f'{ts}{prepared.method}{prepared.path_url}'

  if prepared.body:
    signature_payload += prepared.body

  signature_payload = signature_payload.encode()
  signature = hmac.new(API_KEY_SECRET.encode(), signature_payload,
                       'sha256').hexdigest()

  prepared.headers['FTXUS-KEY'] = API_KEY
  prepared.headers['FTXUS-SIGN'] = signature
  prepared.headers['FTXUS-TS'] = str(ts)

  now = datetime.now()
  dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
  print(
    f'({dt_string})\nSending request type POST to: \n{ENDPOINT}{REQUEST_TYPES[end]}\n'
  )

  response = session.send(prepared)

  data = response.json()
  
  return data
```

func.py:

```
name = 'sub1'
async def new_acc(name):
  payload = {"nickname": name}
  res = await reqs.post('sub', payload)
  print(res)
```

I revised this multiple times with breakpoints and found no error in the signature. If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong and has an idea how to fix it, I'd very much appreciate it

Comment: what API do you use? You could add link to documentation. You could also use `print()` to check what you have in variables. If documentation shows example with signature then you could check if you get the same signature for the same values.

Comment: Here's the API I'm using https://docs.ftx.us/#create-subaccount

Comment: add this information to question - more peole will see it, so more people may help you.

Comment: I can't test it but I see one problem: `payload` has to be `JSON` (`{"nickname": name}`) but `data=payload` creates `form data` (`nickname=name`). You may have to use `json.dumps()` to create correct string.

Comment: Tried it with json previously. Same thing

Comment: there can more problems - JSON is only one of them. It may need more changes. I found Python module for [ftx](https://github.com/quan-digital/ftx) - you can use it or you can see [source code](https://github.com/quan-digital/ftx/blob/v1.2/ftx/api.py) to see how it works.

Comment: That might be very useful. Thanks!

Comment: I see other difference: you use `ftx.us` and module uses `ftx.com`. Code works for me if I try to get data from `ftx.com` but not from `ftx.us`. It may depends on where you created account.